# Why do I have header checksum erro in AutoIt UDP protocol?

Tags: networking, wireshark, autoit

I am using standart UDP function of AutoIt. I tested and dumped UDP packets to loopback interface 127.0.0.1 (send udp packets to myself). I captured it with RawCap, then opened in Wireshark. It showed me that there is a problem with Header Check sum. Why? 
Can I somehow encapsulate HTTP inside UDP (using AutoIt)?

[image]

```
    #include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
#include <WindowsConstants.au3>
#include <ButtonConstants.au3>
HotKeySet("{esc}", "Cleanup")
HotKeySet("{enter}", "sendData")
Global $ConnectedSocket = -1
Global $MainSocket
Local $g_IP, $RogueSocket, $GOOEY, $edit, $input, $butt, $msg
Local $ret, $recv
$g_IP = "127.0.0.1"
$_INCOMING_FLAG = "UDP DATA: "
OnAutoItExitRegister ("Cleanup")


; 1. UDP Listener ### Start The UDP Services ###
;==============================================
UDPStartup()
OnAutoItExitRegister ("Cleanup")

; 1. UDP Listener ### Create a Listening "SOCKET"
;==============================================
$socket = UDPBind($g_IP, 65432)
If @error <> 0 Then Exit

; 3. GUI ### Create a GUI for chatting
;==============================================
$GOOEY = GUICreate("P2P Chat", 300, 200)
$edit = GUICtrlCreateEdit("", 10, 40, 280, 150, $WS_DISABLED)
$input = GUICtrlCreateInput("", 10, 10, 200, 20)
$butt = GUICtrlCreateButton("Send", 210, 10, 80, 20, $BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON)
GUISetState()

; GUI Message Loop
;==============================================
While 1
    $msg = GUIGetMsg()
    If $msg = $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE Then ExitLoop

    If $msg = $butt Then sendData()

    $data = UDPRecv($socket, 200)
    If $data <> "" Then
        GUICtrlSetData($edit, GUICtrlRead($edit) & $_INCOMING_FLAG &$data & @CRLF)
    EndIf
;~  Sleep(50)

WEnd
GUIDelete($GOOEY)

Func sendData()
    If $socket <> 0 Then
        $status = UDPSend($socket, GUICtrlRead($input))
        If $status = 0 Then
            MsgBox(0, "ERROR", "Error while sending UDP message: " & @error)
            Exit
        EndIf

    ElseIf $ret > 0 Then
        ; UPDATE EDIT CONTROL WITH DATA WE SENT
        ;----------------------------------------------------------------
        GUICtrlSetData($edit, GUICtrlRead($edit) & GUICtrlRead($input) & @CRLF)
        GUICtrlSetData($input, "")
    EndIf
EndFunc   ;==>sendData


Func Lookup()
    ; If no connection look for one
    Return 0
EndFunc   ;==>Lookup

Func Cleanup()
    UDPCloseSocket($socket)
    UDPShutdown()
EndFunc   ;==>Cleanup
```

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your answer. If you could give more details on how to reproduce, maybe I could. There is always the possibility to send HTTP packets over UDP, but technically it would only be similar to HTTP since it is defined as going over TCP.

Comment: UDP packets can get lost and UDP isn't really reliable sometimes the data comes in corrupt, unlike TCP.. you will have to keep resending the same UDP packet until it comes back correctly.. but from this disavantage you gain much of speed. When low UDP packetloss occurs you are bypassing all that security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing all of the errant checksums are `0x0000`; in that case, you are probably running into [TCP Checksum Offloading](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Offloading). This is the operating system trying to let the networking hardware calculate the checksum (which will reduce load on the CPU). These checksums are not an error in your application.